# How would manually ending the lifetime of a base class subobject affect accesses to the complete object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Let's start by considering a piece of simple example code:

```cpp
struct Base { int b; };
struct Derived : Base { int d; };

int access_by_ptr() {
  auto *obj = new Derived{1, 2};
  static_cast<Base *>(obj)->~Base();
  return obj->d;  // #1
}

int access_by_ref() {
  auto &obj = *new Derived{1, 2};
  static_cast<Base &>(obj).~Base();
  return obj.d;  // #2
}
```

My question is, according to the standard, are `#1` and `#2` well-defined?

As for `#1`, according to [[basic.life]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#6), when an object's lifetime ends, all pointers that *represent the address of the dead object* are effectively rendered invalid and can only be used in limited ways, which do not include class member access:

> [basic.life]/6: Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated29 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, **any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways**.

Since the layout of base subobjects are unspecified, let's assume that the `Base` subobject in `*obj` in `access_by_ptr` takes the same address as `*obj`, which is commonly adopted by real implementations. When this base subobject's lifetime ends, `obj` can only be used in limited ways because the address it represents is the same as the address of the `Base` subobject. `obj` is then used to access the class member, which is explicitly forbidden by the standard. So I believe `#1` should contain undefined behaviors.

As for `#2`, according to [[basic.life]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#7), when an object's lifetime ends, only those glvalues that refer to the dead object are rendered invalid:

> [basic.life]/7: Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, **any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways**.

Thus, the reference `obj` in `access_by_ref` is not affected and still refer to the `Derived` object after the object's `Base` subobject is destroyed. So I believe `#2` should be OK.

Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, the difference between references and pointers in this case looks subtle, is it intentional?

Comment: "Same pointer value" != "points to the same object", see e.g. `std::launder`. Normally this quirk *causes* UB (when folks forget to `launder`), but in your case it prevents it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl at least for posterity sake, let’s dissect this because we don’t know who this might affect tomorrow.

Comment: _according to [basic.life]/6, when an object's lifetime ends, all pointers that represent the address of the dead object are effectively rendered invalid_ This is wrong

Comment: At the very least, the object is sliced; so no member function referencing base should be used. Destructing the rest of the object becomes a burden. And virtual function calls can no more be trusted. This was one of the motives behind rejecting destructive move semantics when move construction was introduced. In short words, even if you can't explicitly find reference to documents, this will end up leaving you with lots of UB.

Comment: *the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or*: You are not accessing a non-static data member of the object whose lifetime has ended (the `Base` base class subobject), you are accessing a non-static data member of `Derived`, a different object.

Comment: It is never a good idea (AFAIK, its *undefineed behavior*) to manually call a destructor on an object that wasn't created with `placement-new` to begin with

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Could you explain with a bit more details? Maybe I used the word "invalid" wrong. The whole point is that the standard says "these pointers can only be used in limited ways".

Comment: @Artyer Well, it's no doubt that the `Derived` object is still there and in its lifetime. But the whole point is that according to the wording, the pointer `obj` can only be used in limited ways after `Base` subobject is destroyed -- `obj` represents the address of that subobject (I have assumed the `Base` subobject takes the same address as the `Derived` object), although `obj` does not "point to" that subobject.

Comment: @Lancern Yes, and accessing `Derived::d` is none of the points that [basic.life]p6.1 through 6.5 define as UB (Even [p6.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#6.2) because "the object" in that sentence is the `Base` subobject, which `d` is not a member of), so accessing `obj->d` appears to be one of the "limited ways" you can use the pointer